# Model validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

Is it possible to check whether whatever is inputted in the `:password` field is not the same as the `:current_password` field in the model?

Something like

```
validates :current_password, :format => { :with => :password, :message => "Current password can't be the same as the password" }
```

Which does not work what is the right way of writing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I hope you **don't store your password as plain-text**!

And secondly a custom validation will work for you:

```
validate :password_is_not_the_same

def password_is_not_the_same
  errors.add(:password, 'Current password can\'t be the same as the password') if BCrypt::Password.new(password_digest) == password
end
```

---

**Edit:**

```
validate :password_is_not_the_same

def password_is_not_the_same
  errors.add(:password, 'Current password can\'t be the same as the password') if current_password == password
end
```

Comment: Doesn't work how is it checking the :current_password ? , I just want to make sure whatever they put into current_password field is not the same as password the field and give an error saying they cant be the same

Comment: How are your passwords stored? (Hopefully not) as plain-text, as MD5/SHA hash, or using Bcyrpt? (This example assumes you're using Bcrypt.)

Comment: But I do not want to check the password value in the database I just want to check what they in-putted in the form with current_password in the form also.

Comment: So `current_password` is a field in the model containing the password as plain-text?

Comment: No it isn't, I just want to check whatever is entered into the current_password field is not the same as whatever is entered into the "new" password field. just a simple client side check.

Comment: So it's stored as plain-text. ;) Updated the answer.

Comment: I tried using your code but does not give any error's when they are the same

Comment: It possible that *devise* overwrites the fields. Sorry, no xp with devise.

Comment: Possible but I just want to check what's in-putted... I'm using client side validation so I'm not even clicking submit, Just like how password says it does not match the confirmation I want a similar thing for current_password and password